# Error 401 Unauthorized in spring boot / spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I added spring security dependency, after that I started the server, everything goes well. As a result I get a form with Username and password, I enter `user` as username and as a password the one I get in the console,

```
Using generated security password: 8c3450f7-ab6c-419e-bd69-431ed336eeaa
```

But I always get username or password are incorrect.

Class `Security`:

```
package security;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                         
    }
}
```

Here is the link I'm trying to access **http://localhost:8081/users**

Any ideas about mistakes I'm making?

Class `UserController`:

```
RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")     // localhosr:8080/users
public class userController {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping
    public String getUser() {
        return " get user was called ";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public UserResponse createUser(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
        
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userRequest, userDto);
        
        UserDto createUser = userService.createUser(userDto);
        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(createUser, userResponse);
        
        return userResponse ;
    }
    
    @PutMapping
    public String updateUser() {
        return " update user was called ";
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping
    public String deleteUser() {
        return " delete user was called ";
    }
}
```

In insomnia, for Get Method, I'm getting error 401 Unauthorized

PS: I've removed the class `WebSecurity`, and I'm trying to access localhost:8081/users, I'm always getting a login form and can't get logged in.

Comment: `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users")` allows only POST requests. You would want to use something like `antMatchers("/users")` instead, which allows any kind of request.  Please note, this will make `/users` endpoint public.

Comment: But i want to allow only Post requests for creating users, anything else needs to be logged in , I tried  antMatchers("/users"), but it always shows me login form

Comment: @dEs12ZER The way you posted your question, it was hard to understand and to read. Please take your time and look through the edits that have been made to your post, to understand what to look out for in the future. You should not rely on others to make your posts legible

Answer (score -1):

You will configuration to ALL end-point to required authenticated by "anyRequest().authenticated()". So, ofc you will get 401 all time.

**First way**

You can configuration all path requires one-by-one. Like:

- `.antMatchers("/to/path/**").isAuthenticated()` If you required auth.
- `.antMatchers("/to/path/**").isAnonymous()` If you required no-auth, so you will get 401 again with auth
- `.antMatchers("/to/path/**").permitAll()` It does matter user was authenticated or not
- `.antMatchers("/to/path/**").hasRole(...)` Refined regulation (in future)

**Second way:**

I recommend use it with: "anyRequest().permitAll()"

Use annotation on configuration class:

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
  ...
}
```

After it, you can control method level. Example:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") // this isAuthenticated() see above first way
@PutMapping
public String updateUser() {
   ...
}
```

Those that do not have a security annotation are the default permitAll.

Link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security

**Side note:**
It also work on spring react (webflux), just replace `EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(...)` with: `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity`. And of course, the setting is a bit different, but this can be searched online.